# Circulant Matrices and Ring of Polinomials

Tags: polynomials, group-isomorphism, vector-space-isomorphism

I am having problem to proove that the group of circulant Matrices of size nxn, $C_n$ is isomorphic to $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{<x^n-1>}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the circulant matrix with top row $
\pmatrix{0&1&0&\cdots&0}$. Then each circulant matrix is a polynomial in $A$.
Moreover $A$ has minimum polynomial $X^n-1$.

Comment: I dont get it, how you make the isomorphism?